# form_open with array is not working

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I'm having trouble on using my array after I passed it through form_open in php. I'm using codeigniter with mvc pattern

Here's my sample code in view:

```
<?php 
    $fdata=array("ID"=>$id,
        "DOC_CODE"=>$doc_code,
        "DOC_NAME"=>$doc_name); ?>

<div>
    <?php echo form_open("document", $fdata, "target='_blank'");?>
        ......
    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
</div>
```

And in controller:

```
//first try
public function login() {
    print_r($fdata);
}

//second try
public function login(fdata) {
    print_r($fdata);
}
```

the result is Message: Undefined index: fdata

Answer (score 2):

form_open function allow max two parameters

> 1=> post url
>
> 2=> attribute array

in your case you need to put "target='_blank'" in attribute array

```
<?php 
$fdata = array("ID"=>$id,
    "DOC_CODE"=>$doc_code,
    "DOC_NAME"=>$doc_name,
    "target" => "_blank"  ); ?>

<div>
<?php echo form_open("document", $fdata);?>
    ......
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
</div>
```

now it should work

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
<?php echo form_open("document/".$fdata, "target='_blank'");?>
```

in your controller

```
public function login($fdata) {
   print_r($fdata);
}
```

Comment: I'm using array as parameter

Comment: Why you append and array (`$fdata`) to the POST URL? That makes no sense.